# Building Web-Service client from existing WSDL file using java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I've been tasked with building a web service in java, and I've been given an existing WSDL file which seems to define everything. I need to build my java around/using this (Not consuming it though) . How would I go about using this in eclipse?

I've tried going "New Web Service Client" and selecting the WSDL However the code it generates doesn't include any of the methods (which is just 1) or the parameters from the WSDL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Apache CXF WSDL to Java for doing this thing.Look at here [Click here](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/wsdl-to-java.html) and also google it for more details

Also you can use SoapUi for doing this. I think soapUi way is more easy than the previous method [click for soapUI tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/tips/generating-client-java-code)

WSDL consist every detail about how your web service should look like and the functionality

Answer (score 1):

I think if you're trying to write the web service using an existing WSDL, you're probably going about it the wrong way. It looks like from the command that it's trying to build you a client, not a server.

I had some luck with the WSDL-first tutorial in the Spring-WS library. I would take a look at that.

http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/tutorial.html